# I can read Name of the release, but not able to read can't read ReleaseDate from the release in rally

Tags: javascript, rally

columnValue = columnValue.get('Name');

give me Name of the release
but not able to read ReleaseDate

columnvalue1 = columnValue.get('ReleaseEndDate');

this gives me error
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

This is my release object

columnValue value

j {phantom: false, internalId: "ext-record-2", raw: Object, data: Object, modified: Object…}

data: Object
CreationDate: null
GrossEstimateConversionRatio: ""

Name: "Release 24"
Notes: ""
ObjectID: 12788620953
PlannedVelocity: null

Project: ""
ReleaseDate: Wed Sep 17 2014 10:29:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

ReleaseStartDate: Wed Jul 23 2014 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
RevisionHistory: ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release object has `ReleaseStartDate` and `ReleaseDate`. There is no ReleaseEndDate in [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/).

Use ReleaseDate.

Try [this example](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/example/simple-grid) of a simple grid from the guide. Replace `model: 'userstory'` with `model: 'release'`, and use config:

```
columnCfgs:[
    'Name',
    'ReleaseStartDate',
    'ReleaseDate'
]
```

You should see ReleaseDate.

Then try [custom data example](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/example/custom-data-grid) from the grid that requires explicit fetching of ReleaseDate. Modify that example to display a grid of releases instead of a grid of user stories. You may do something like this to create a custom column Release Dates based on values of both ReleaseStartDate and ReleaseDate:

```
launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'release',
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            load: this._onDataLoaded,
            scope: this
        },
        fetch: ['Name', 'ReleaseStartDate', 'ReleaseDate']
        //fetch: ['Name', 'ReleaseStartDate']
    });
},
 _onDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
    var records = _.map(data, function(record) {
        console.log(record);
        return Ext.apply({
            ReleaseDates: record.get('ReleaseStartDate') + " -- " + record.get('ReleaseDate')
        }, record.getData());
    });

    this.add({
        xtype: 'rallygrid',
        showPagingToolbar: false,
        showRowActionsColumn: false,
        editable: false,
        store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
            data: records
        }),
        columnCfgs: [
            {
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'Name'
            },
            {
                text: 'Release Dates',
                dataIndex: 'ReleaseDates',
                flex: 1
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

This should also display ReleaseDate as long as fetch includes ReleaseDate `fetch: ['Name', 'ReleaseStartDate',ReleaseDate']`

The problem is likely to be related to your code. Start with working examples as above and see if ReleaseDate is returned.

Comment: ya I tried those ones also..same error I am getting

Comment: I updated my post with grid examples that display ReleaseDate.